# linkTo not picking up parameters

Tags: ember.js

I want to `{{linkTo}}` the `/activities/:user/:by_date` route:

```
this.resource('activities', { path: '/activities' }, function() {
    this.route('by_date', {path: '/:user/:by_date'});
});
```

If I directly put the parameters into the URL the controller behaves correctly and I just want my application template to linkTo this URL with a reasonable hardcoded set of values for these parameters. I am attempting to do this by setting an instance variable in the `ApplicationController`:

```
activityDefaults: {user:1, by_date:"2013-07-01"}
```

I think have the linkTo in the application template:

```
{{#linkTo "activities.by_date" activityDefaults}}Activities{{/linkTo}}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, resolving the URL to:

```
/activities/undefined/undefined
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= UPDATE -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

I've tried making the `activityDefaults` an Ember object:

```
module.exports = activityDefaults = Ember.Object.create({
    user_id: 1, 
    by_date: "2012-07-12"
});
```

And then I've added a serializer to the `ActivitiesByDateController`:

```
serialize: function(model) {
    return {
        user_id: model.get('user_id'), 
        by_date: model.get('by_date')
    };
}
```

The `{{linkTo}}` still doesn't work but there are subtle differences. Hovering over the link you no longer see any URL beyond the base URL (note: before it had `/activities/undefined/undefined`). Also when you click on the link it sends the following message to the browser's console:

> This linkTo is in an inactive loading state because at least one of its parameters' presently has a null/undefined value, or the provided route name is invalid.

NOTE:
I did change the inconsistent use of on_date/by_date to be consistently using the by_date naming convention. I am a little but blurry on when Ember converts underscored variables and converts them to camelCase. I don't think I'm running into that but it's bugging me in the back of my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You should hook into the `serialize` function and provide the dynamic segments your URL resolution needs (assuming `user_id` and `on_date` are properties available on your `Activity` model):

```
App.ActivitiesByDateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  ...
  serialize: function(model) {
    return {
      user_id: model.get('user_id'), 
      on_date: model.get('on_date')
    };
  }
});
```

Then assuming further you have where your `linkTo` helper lives `activity` as the model available, it would look like this:

```
{{#linkTo "activities.by_date" activity}}Activities{{/linkTo}}
```

> Also worth mentioning is that if you name your route `on_date` you should name your template the same way or vice versa. Ember works a lot with conventions and if you don't want yourself running into nasty errors at some point you should be consistent with naming's in your app.

That said, IMO you should rename your route in your router map also `by_date` the dynamic segment can have a different name since you are going to pick it up in the `serialize` hook later on.

```
this.resource('activities', { path: '/activities' }, function() {
  this.route('by_date', {path: '/:user/:on_date'});
});
```

If you where now asking *"how does he know that my route is called `ActivitiesByDateRoute`?"* I saw it on another question of yours :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: LOL. Yes I started with the ByDate convention and then started liking OnDate better. I had always intended to make them consistent but hadn't realised that this might actually cause problems due to naming convention assumptions on Ember's part. One more reason to be consistent I guess.

Comment: BTW, I did try the `serialize` method but it didn't work for me. Initially I thought this was because the `activityDefaults` isn't a Ember object and therefore doesn't have a get() method but I tried making a direct assignment in the serializer -- such as `user_id: model.user_id` -- and that failed too. Does the serializer enforce the parameter sent to it be an Ember object?

Comment: As a final step I did try making `activityDefaults` an Ember object but unless I screwed up the scope of that object it also appears to not behaving correctly. Note: when I click on the linkTo link now it sends the message "This linkTo is in an inactive loading state because at least one of its parameters' presently has a null/undefined value". I'll add the code snippet to the question.